# naming element by looping names of list

Tags: r, for-loop

Sorry about the probable misleading title and possible post duplication

I want to create a loop that will parse a list elements 1:4 and its one be set in a data.frame with the name of the element chosen by the loop.
I am starting with a list:

```
> names(peakAnnoList_chip)
[1] "CAPAN1_px8_JunB"    "CAPAN1_px13_JunB"   "Panc1_13_cjun"      "Panc1_px8_old_cJun"

> class(peakAnnoList_chip)
[1] "list"
```

then I get the first element:

```
> CAPAN1_px8_JunB <- as.data.frame(peakAnnoList_chip[[1]]@anno)
> class(CAPAN1_px8_JunB)
[1] "data.frame"
```

So that in the end I can do:

```
write.table(CAPAN1_px8_JunB, 
            file = "CAPAN1_px8_JunB_annotation.txt",
            sep = "\t", 
            quote = F,
            row.names = F)
```

but there I can not find an elegant way to set the specific name (CAPAN1_px8_JunB) to the data.frame

any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is `lapply` to loop over the names of the 'peakAnnoList_chip', extract the 'anno' and write it to different datasets with `write.table`

```
lapply(names(peakAnnoList_chip), function(nm) 
        write.table(peakAnnoList_chip[[nm]]@anno, 
    file = paste0(nm, "_annotation.txt"), sep="\t", quote = FALSE))
```

---

Or another option is `Map`

```
Map(function(dat, nm) write.table(dat@nno, file =
      paste0(nm, "_annotation.txt"), sep="\t", quote = FALSE),
              peakAnnoList_chip, names(peakAnnoList_chip))
```

---

Or with `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
imap(peakAnnoList_chip, ~ write.table(.x, file = str_c(.y, 
            "_annotation.txt"), sep="\t", quote = FALSE))
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will test it.
is there also an elegant way to do something to name in a loop the output of the :
CAPAN1_px8_JunB <- as.data.frame(peakAnnoList_chip[[1]]@anno)

Comment: @sunta3iouxos  I would say not to create multiple objects in the global environment as it inefficient and create issues

Comment: I definitely understand this (better to iterate all special data into the same elements) but there are cases that I would like to have all the elements for future reference since the original files might not exist anymore, or even share those elements.

Comment: @sunta3iouxos In that case, you can remove the `write.csv` part and store it in a `list` and later write it. i.e. `lst1 <- lapply(names(peakAnnoList_chip), function(nm) peakAnnoList_chip[[nm]]@anno); names(lst1) <- names(peakAnnoList_chip); list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)` for creating objects in the global env

Comment: sorry, have not test it yet